# Is it possible to prompt for restarting the machine after installation using WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, reboot

Is it possible to prompt for restarting the machine after installation using WiX?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>

    <Product
        Name = 'Sample App'
        Id = 'PRODUCT-GUID-HERE'
        UpgradeCode = 'UPGRADE-GUID-HERE'
        Language = '1033'
        Version = 'YOUR-APP-VERSION-HERE'
        Manufacturer = 'YOU!'>

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize"/>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

I think I got it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371101(VS.85).aspx) for the `REBOOT` property in Windows Installer.

i.e.:

```
<Property Id="REBOOT"><![CDATA[Force]]></Property>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the REBOOT property of WiX in the Product.wxs file of your setup to get a restart prompt. The syntax is:

```
<Property Id="REBOOT" Value="Force"></Property>
```